# how to install xorg intel driver in the stable/testing debian os to support intel GMA3150 video

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, intel-graphics

GMA3150 intel video chipset requires xf86-video-intel 2.10.0 video driver.

stable debian (lenny) has 2.3.2 version of xf86-video-intel driver.
testing debian (squeeze) has 2.9.1. version.
unstable debian (sid) has 2.9.1 version.
and only experimental debian has 2.12.0 version.

question. how to install 2.10.0 driver (with GMA3150 support) on testing or unstable debian version?

we use debian in our products and unfortunately it's completely impossible to use experimental version in production.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download the .deb file and any dependencies it needs from the mirror, then use `dpkg -i` to install the package manually

Comment: i believe it's impossible to simply download required package and install it manually. because this package depends on packages from experimental distributive. in the result i will download all packages from experimental debian and my system becomes 'experimental' too.

Comment: I would suggest trying to isolate the dependency tree, so you could only have one strain of software that needed to be from experimental. So for instance, you could possibly have xorg, and the graphics stack from experimental, and the rest of the system from squeeze or where ever.

Comment: it works. great.

what i did:
- installed jhbuild utility
- prepared build environment using jhbuild (read more information here http://www.x.org/wiki/JhBuildInstructions)
- compiled the latest Xorg server with intel driver
- compiled and installed 2.6.34 kernel with intel video card support
- started new X server

now my intel video card works perfectly in the debian 5.0.

Thanks!